# How to access the source code for an imported class in Java?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

In some code I'm looking at, there was this import statement. 
`import husaynhakeem.io.facedetector.models.FaceBounds`
How do I find the code in this `FaceBounds` class? I have tried looking on the user's github but I have not been able to find the actual class. The only classes I find are `Facing.kt`, `Orientation.kt` and `models.kt` but not the `Facebounds` class.  https://github.com/husaynhakeem/android-face-detector/tree/master/facedetector/src/main/java/husaynhakeem/io/facedetector/models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data class FaceBounds(val id: Int, val box: Rect)`

It's in `models.kt`